# Xamarin Forms Empty TableSection in Xamarin.iOS leaves empty space at the top of tableView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have a TableView in Xamarin Forms with multiple cells.I want TableSection Title to be empty.Now the problem is when title is empty there is empty gray space at the top of the table.[this is how my table is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eufyf.png)

Any help?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the actual screen? Also the code or XAML you use to produce the screen?

Comment: There is a transparent background color, you can set all of your views to be White or transparent in order to do what you need even the background color of the ContentPage

Comment: I cant set background color as white as it will have some space between my cells and other content on the page